# <textarea> tag doesn't record response in HTML form

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, sharepoint

I have created an HTML form that works perfectly and sends information recorded in the form via AJAX to a sharepoint list, and populates the correct columns accordingly. After changing the input type from `<input>` to `<textarea>`, the input is no longer recorded and sent via AJAX to the sharepoint list.

The only thing that I have changed in my HTML code is.

```
 <div class="elements">
                    <label for="Notes"> Notes :</label>
                    <input type="text" align= "left" id="dNotes" name="Notes" placeholder="Please provide notes">
                </div>
                <div class="submit">
                    <input type="submit" id="btn" name="btn" class="btn" value="Submit" />
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
                </SharePoint:FormDigest>
            </form>
```

to this: (is there anyway to record a text area as an input?)

```
<div class="elements">
                    <label for="dNotes"> Notes :</label>
                    <textarea name ="dNotes" rows="5" cols="20"></textarea><br/>
                </div>
                <div class="submit">
                    <input type="submit" id="btn" name="btn" class="btn" value="Submit" />
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
                </SharePoint:FormDigest>
            </form>
```

Comment: *"The only thing that's changed"* - is that you've removed `id=dNotes` from the (now) text area (and changed its `name=`) - so you'd *also* need to change the js that reads the input if you don't give it the same id/name

Comment: @freedomn-m I understand that I changed that, I will add the section of my JS that reads and sends this. But it uses my id tag to record the inputs, but there is no id attribute for text area, which is why I am confused

Comment: Yes, knowing your js would help to identify the issue.  If you have `$("#dNotes").val()` then it will stop working if you don't have an element with `id=dNotes`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems for input you use id="dNotes" name="Notes", and for textarea you use no id and name="dNotes". I recommend to control these values, most probably it Will work after changing these values.

Comment: I wasn't aware the ID attribute was available for the <textarea> tag. Simple solutions can be the hardest ones I swear haha. Thank you